# Hankel transform of exponential involving square root argument without HT

Tags: asymptotics, approximation, fourier-transform, integral-transforms

Given integral to investigate asymptotic behaviour on:

$$A=Re\int_{0}^{\infty} J_0(xs) e^{-iw{\sqrt {gx}}}xdx$$
for large $s$ and $w$

$\sqrt{2 / \pi x} cos(x-(2n+1)\pi/4)=J_n(x)$

Want to investigate assymptotics without Henkel transform. The J function is 0th Bessel function.
The $\sqrt{x}$ term in exponential part and complex messes up attempts to approximate.

Any ideas on how to take the transform? Maybe substitution or something

Comment: Can you please clarify any constraints on $g$? (e.g. $g>0$?) And what is $w$?

Comment: @StevenClark corrected problem statement, also turns out no need for Hankel, apologies. upvoted the answer though

Comment: The title and last sentence are inconsistent with your new problem statement. I'm not sure I understand your motivation for redefining the problem. Many times Mathematica gives the same result whether you use the Integrate function or express the integral as a transform, and sometimes gives a result for the transform expression when it can't seem to derive a result for the integral via the Integrate function.

Comment: In this case Mathematica provides a different result when using the Integrate function but the result is only valid for the condition $\Im\left(\sqrt{g}\,t\right)<0$ which is why I asked you about constraints on $g$ which you still haven't clarified. And $w$ still makes no sense.

Comment: @StevenClark thank you! g is positive thought, gravity constant. $w$ is just large finite number, when g<0 the problem reduced to real exponent

Comment: Ok, I see now you replaced $t$ with $w$ in the integral. Since you're only interested in the real part, have you considered splitting the integral? Since $e^{-i\,w\,\sqrt{g\,x}}=\cos\left(w\,\sqrt{g\,x}\right)-i\,\sin\left(w\,\sqrt{g\,x}\right)$, $\int_0^{\infty} J_0(x\,s)\,e^{-i\,w\,\sqrt{g\,x}}\,x\,dx=\int_0^{\infty} J_0(x\,s)\,\cos\left(w\,\sqrt{g x}\right)\,x\,dx-i \int_0^{\infty} J_0(x\,s)\,\sin\left(w\,\sqrt{g\,x}\right)\,x\,dx$ and both integrands on the right side are strictly real assuming $s\ge0\land w>0\land g>0$.

Comment: @StevenClark Bessel function is real $\sqrt{2 / \pi x} cos(x-(2n+1)\pi/4)=J_n(x)$, the second integral with sine vanishes, arguments of different orders - square root X and X are problematic to deal with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you know what is the form of the $J_0(xs)$, then you can rewrite it into two exponential terms, in which one gives zero contribution. For the other term, you can apply method of stationary phase by finding where the maximum is attained.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica defines the Hankel transform ([see Details and Options here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HankelTransform.html)) as

$$\mathcal{H}_{r,v}\left[f(r)\right](s)=\int_0^\infty r\,f(r)\,J_v(r s)\,dr\tag{1}$$

and (using $v=0$ and replacing $r$ with $x$) evaluates the Hankel transform of

$$f(x)=e^{-i\,t\,\sqrt{g\,x}}\tag{2}$$
as

$$\mathcal{H}_{x,0}\left[e^{-i\,t\,\sqrt{g\,x}}\right](s)=\frac{\sqrt{2} G_{1,3}^{3,1}\left(\frac{g^2 t^4}{64 s^2}|
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 \frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4} \\
\end{array}
\right)}{\pi ^{3/2} s^2}\,,\quad s\geq 0\tag{3}$$

where $G$ is the [Meijer G-Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeijerG-Function.html).